# rename numbers of files with cmd

Tags: rename, file-rename

I have a lot of files named like this

```
  "icon_location.png@2x.png" "icon_logo.png@2x.png" "btn_tip.png@2x.png" ......
```

And I want to rename them as

```
  "icon_location@2x.png" "icon_logo@2x.png" "btn_tip@2x.png" .....
```

In short, the extra ".png" before '@2x.png' should be removed. I try hard in cmd with the command "ren", but I can not find the right form to achieve my purpose. Any one knows? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have additional tools like sed and awk? Are you ready to use python to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Write a console program to do this task simply workout.

Use C# program and use this to get files name as String Array.

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Path-to-your-directory");
```

:-)